# Firebase Push notification not working in iOS 11

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios11

Firebase push notifications were working until iOS 11 was released. Now looks like on iOS 11 i am not getting push notifications.
I added the line 'FirebaseInstanceID', "2.0.0" in the podfile too. But still i am not receiving any notifications.

Please help.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing.  The solution that has been presented is to update FirebaseInstanceID but alas this has not solved for me.  This is becoming an increasingly big issue.  I will work towards a solution but if anyone has any insight into a true solution, I’m all ears.

Comment: Is Swift 3 required for iOS 11.x ?

Comment: @studiobrain: I also tried updating firebase to the latest version. Even then it does not work for me. Please help if anybody has any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with push notifications and scheduled push notifications on iOS 11.1 by replicating the same code present in the sample firebase project - https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging

The steps given here are clear and helps you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still having the issue, you can try my solution. Mine is swift 3 project. In your podfile. Please follow the sequence.

`pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '2.0.0'
  pod 'FirebaseInstanceID' , '2.0.0'`

In the appDelegate file, put this code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

Uninstall the app and try rebuild at your device. (Please ensure your provision profile for development is included with your tested device). This worked for me.